# Image filepath not loading in view in Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to load images into a view using the file path in different ways like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <img alt="image0" src="static/images/folklore0.png">
    <img alt="image1" src="static/folklore1.png">
    <img alt="image2" src="templates/fragments/folklore2.png">
    <img alt="THimage0"  th:src="@{static/images/folklore0.png}">
    <img alt="THimage1"  th:src="@{static/folklore1.png}">
    <img alt="THimage2"  th:src="@{templates/fragments/folklore2.png}">
</div>
```

None of my attempts are working, the result I'm getting is [image: images in browser]

I've tried placing my images in alot of different locations and different path types (like absolute path) and from what I can find is that my views should be able to find resources placed in the `resource` folder. I am using thymeleaf and my templates have no problem of accessing thymeleaf fragments located in `resources/templates/fragments/`.

My project structure is like so:

[image: project structure]

I've tried to google the answer but I can't manage to solve it... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use `th:src="@{/static/images/folklore0.png}"`.

Comment: Doesn't work :/ @M.Deinum

Comment: I've also tried with other pictures and image types like .jpg to no avail

Comment: That should work, so there must be something you aren't showing here that is influencing how things are being resolved.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction of editing my question? @M.Deinum

Comment: well I feel kind of retarded now.. So it seem that the base directory is the ```static``` folder and not the ```resources``` folder, so that the path needed to locate should just have excluded ```/static```. It works with ```th:src="@{/images/folklore0.png}"```